# no internet on android emulator

Tags: windows-10, android-emulator, visual-studio-2022, maui

I've been busy with .NET MAUI building an app. Problem I have now is that I'm trying to log in into my identityserver, which needs an internet connection.
But the browser isn't loading any pages. I can see the request coming into my identityserver, but the pages just freezes and stops loading. I can't load any other page as well.
I can play youtube video's with the app, so there is a 'fast' internet connection.

Specs:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2022 17.4.0

The hyper-v network connection on my local machine shows it is sending data, just not receiving:

[image: hyperv]

Tried to change some settings here as well, like changing the DNS to 8.8.8.8, but to no avail.

Any idea's?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking

Comment: I met the same problem before, the cause of the problem is the difference between local DNS and the DNS on android emulator. You can check the local DNS and set it on the emulator.